# `ember install emberfire` failed, is ember-cli-emberfire a better route with Node 6.2.2?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, firebase, ember-cli, emberfire

### Cannot find module 'q' and more…

When I run `ember install emberfire` in an existing Ember app, I get `Cannot find module 'q'`.

I searched the issue, tried `npm cache clean` and `npm install q`.

Now, `ember install emberfire` throws `Cannot find module '../function/makeIterator_'` and I'm reluctant to go further.

However, at [npm-embercli-emberfire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-emberfire) the advice is to install via Bower with `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-emberfire` - to quote:

1. This repo lists emberFire as a bower dependency
2. It runs `bower install` as the npm postinstall script
3. it exports a tree containing both the firebase and emberFire libraries

### Do node 6.2.2 and ember-cli play nicely yet?

Since the machinations of npm and Node become an irritating mystery when I'm trying to focus on an Ember ([tutorial](https://youtu.be/-gd6LRt7Dcg?t=189)) app, I'd like to know:

- how running `ember install emberfire` differs, and if running it before running the npm-recommended command is an issue?
- If it's okay to run ember-cli with node 6.2.2 - if not, suggestions?

### My setup

- OS X 10.11.6 (and just had to `chown -R` usr/local after an OS X update).
- node 6.2.2 (which apparently "has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.")
- Ember: 1.13.15
- ember-cli: 1.13.15
- ember-data: 2.7.0
- node: 6.2.2
- npm: 2.14.10
- emberfire: 2.0.1
- ember-cli-emberfire: 0.0.1

#### The full error readout:

```
$ ember install emberfire
version: 1.13.15
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
installing emberfire
  identical app/adapters/application.js
Cannot find module 'q'
Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/projects/solutions-log/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install q
solutions-log@0.0.0 /Users/admin/projects/solutions-log
└── q@1.4.1 

$ ember install emberfire
version: 1.13.15
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
installing emberfire
  identical app/adapters/application.js
Cannot find module '../function/makeIterator_'
Error: Cannot find module '../function/makeIterator_'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/projects/solutions-log/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/mout/array/collect.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Comment: A downvote with no comment?

Comment: What version of EmberFire are you using? I assume its the latest if so it doesn't appear to fit their compatibility table https://github.com/firebase/emberfire#compatibility

Comment: Can you track down where am module named 'q' is being imported? You can't just npm install q... also, 1.13 may not be compatible with the walkthrough you're using. What CLI version are you using?

Comment: Versions added above. Thanks @Hillboy - I only found the table after installing but the versions of ember-data and emberfire are compatible in my setup.

Comment: @sheriffderek - can't easily work out what 'q' is or where it's needed (see error messages above). Did manage an install of emberfire using [ember-cli-emberfire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-emberfire) but now discover the guide on the that page is also outdated. Will try to go ahead and see what happens. Main issue is I don't get why `ember install emberfire` fails.

Comment: `version: 1.13.15` that version of Ember CLI won't work properly with Node 6 due to breaking changes in the latter.

Comment: So I'll downgrade to node 5 and try again. Wish there were an easier one-stop way to update a setup and keep track of incompatibilities at a glance.

Comment: Just for completion on downgrading node in OS X with Homebrew: `$ brew search node` found `Caskroom/versions/node5`, `$ brew unlink node`, `brew install homebrew/versions/node5` then finally `brew link --overwrite node5` - gives v5.12.0